# How to merge return value of multiple param decorators?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, nestjs, decorator

I have multiple parameter decorators:

```
import type { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const Sort = createParamDecorator(
  async (_: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // some async stuff
    return { sort: { field1: 1, field2: -1 } };
  },
);

export const Pagination = createParamDecorator(
  async (_: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // some async stuff
    return { page: 1, limit: 1 };
  },
);
```

I am trying to compose these decorators:

```
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

export const PaginationSort = () =>
  applyDecorators(
    Pagination(),
    Sort(),
  );
```

But when I use `PaginationSort` decorator in my controller, I only receive the value from `Sort` decorator:

```
@Controller()
class MyController {
  @Get()
  async find(@PaginationSort() pagination: PaginationSortEntity) {
    console.log(pagination); // => { sort: { field1: 1, field2: -1 } }
  }
}
```

#### How can I merge return values of both decorators to have

#### `{ sort: { field1: 1, field2: -1 }, page: 1, limit: 1 }` ?

I could use decorators separately on different method parameters, but in reality I am combining much more than just 2 decorators.

Comment: DO you attach these values to the req at all, or are they just hard coded returns?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I could do this in each decorator:
`req.paginationSort ??= {}; return Object.assign(req.paginationSort, paginationOrSortReturnValue);`
But I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel No, I do not attach these values to the req, they are not hardcoded, they are calculated from the request's query parameters. These decorators are pure functions and I want to compose them in a functional way, without mutating anything.

Comment: If the values aren't attached to the request at all, then the decorators will not have context into what other decorators have already set, so you won't be able to combine the two values together